# How can my shell script control the placement of a zenity window?

Tags: shell, x11, zenity

I'm using `zenity` to post a simple notification when my spam-filter daemon filters a group of messages.  Currently this message is posted to the middle of the screen, which is obtrusive.  I want to post it to the upper left corner.  However, `zenity` does not honor the `-geometry` option which is supposed to be standard for all X applications, and its documentation gives options for controlling window height and width, but not placement.

Is there a way to control the (x,y) coordinate at which a `zenity` window is posted?

If not, is there a way to solve this problem by tinkering with X resources or the window manager (I'm using the `fvwm`)?

---

**EDIT**: The following do not work in `~/.fvwm2rc` (`fvwm` version 2.5.26):

```
Style "Information" PositionPlacement -0 -0
Style "Zenity" PositionPlacement -0 -0
```

They also don't work with the `-0 -0` dropped, as suggested in the man page.
(The window title for `zenity --info` is "Information".)

Interestingly, `zenity` was ignoring my earlier window-manager directive that windows should be placed manually by default.

---

**EDIT**:

Among many other fascinating pieces of information, `xprop(1)` reports this about the `zenity` window:

```
_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE(ATOM) = _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DIALOG
WM_NORMAL_HINTS(WM_SIZE_HINTS):
                program specified location: 0, 0
                program specified minimum size: 307 by 128
                program specified maximum size: 307 by 128
                window gravity: NorthWest
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "zenity", "Zenity"
WM_ICON_NAME(STRING) = "Information"
WM_NAME(STRING) = "Information"
```

Despite this apparently encouraging report, the window is not in fact posted at the location 0,0 :-(

I know the `Style` command is taking effect because I added the `!Borders` option, and sure enough the `zenity` window posts without borders... but still in the center of the damn screen!

Comment: Have you tried EWMHIgnoreStateHints and EWMHIgnoreWindowType?

Answer (score 4):

I do it by using `wmctrl` in a subshell. Example:

```
((sleep .4;wmctrl -r TeaTimer -R TeaTimer -e 0,50,20,-1,-1)
for ((a=$LIMIT; a > 0; a--)); do
# for loop generates text, not shown
done
wmctrl -R TeaTimer
) | zenity --progress --title="TeaTimer" --percentage=0
```

First `wmctrl` moves zenity to upper left, second moves it to
current workspace. See a [full example](http://user.cavenet.com/rolandl/timer.txt).

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the "old" way of doing this, using FvwmEvent.

```
AddToFunc StartFunction I Module FvwmEvent FvwmEvent-MoveWindow

DestroyModuleConfig FvwmEvent-MoveWindow: *
*FvwmEvent-MoveWindow: Cmd Function
*FvwmEvent-MoveWindow: add_window MoveZenity

DestroyFunc MoveZenity
AddToFunc   MoveZenity
+ I ThisWindow ("zenity") Move -0 -0
```

If this still doesn't work (or you are determined to get it working using PositionPlacement) you could try

```
BugOpts ExplainWindowPlacement
```

Fvwm will then write debugging output to it's logfile (or to the console, depending on your setup) explaining how it is placing windows (and why it is doing so).

Also just fyi, if you want to get information about a window you can use the FvwmIdent module to get this information (instead of xprop, though both work fine).

Comment: Terrifying.  I probably won't try this, but +1 for lots of fvwm fu.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is definitely possible with the proper help from window manager. For example, with xmonad it would be one line of code...

My fvwm is little rusty, but it seems like something along the lines of:

```
Style "zenity" PositionPlacement -0 -0
```

in your fvwm2rc should do the trick.

EDIT: Notice the lowercase "zenity" since, according to the docs, it should match not only window title, but window class as well (which you can find out using "xprop" utility: launch it and point to window in question).

According to xprop, zenity window has two interesting properties:

1. It has `_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE(ATOM) = _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DIALOG`, indicating that it is a dialog window
2. It has `WM_TRANSIENT_FOR(WINDOW): window id # <some window id here>`, indicating the main window for which it is a dialog (in my case - xterm window)

So, if my suggestion does not work, then it is almost certainly because fvwm handles dialogs in a special way - either due to configuration or due to hardcoded behavoir.

You can try adding "`EWMHIgnoreWindowType`" to the style of zenity windows, which should hopefuly made fvwm ignore those hints

Comment: +1 for the helpful suggestion, but actually it doesn't work, as I have edited my question to reflect.

Comment: No luck.  If you have any other ideas, please let me know.

Comment: try dropping quotes around "zenity" like this:

     Style zenity PositionPlacement -0 -0

Comment: oh, and try adding EWMHIgnoreStateHints as well

Comment: Please could you mention your xmonad one-liner? Thanks!

Comment: Paul, see http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Hooks-Place.html for examples

Answer (score 0):

Try devilspie:  http://burtonini.com/blog/computers/devilspie/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wmctrl` to get the windowid, then `xdotool` to place it wherever you want. Simple and adaptable to many types of environments.

```
 ## Arg 1 - Pid of window to move.
 ## Arg 2 - X-Coord.
 ## Arg 3 - Y-Coord. 
function move_win() { 
 xdotool windowmove $(wmctrl -lp | grep ${1} | cut -d' ' -f1) ${2} ${3}
}
```

E.g.  `$> move_win $(pidof zenity) 0 0`

Comment: I receive the error message `Warning: XTEST extension unavailable on '(null)'. Some functionality may be disabled; See 'man xdotool' for more info.
Too few arguments (got 1, minimum is 2)` with your example. Do you know what is going wrong?